# how to put URL inside of laravel blade

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have database structure like Book & download link ..

```
$book= new Book();
$book->name = $request->Input(['name']);
$book->download_link = $request->Input(['download_link']); // eg. https://bnbooks.com/1234
$book->save();
```

now if i want to give this in blade page ..like download link..how do i put in `href` tag so that it will redirect the user to that page?

```
<a href="{{URL::to($book->download_link)}}">{{$book->name}}</a>
// This doesn't work
```

Comment: `URL::to()` adds the base url so if you have added whole path in download link then just add like `href="{{$book->download_link}}"`

Answer (score 0):

`URL::to` is a function to create a url on your site from only the path (for example `/foo/bar`). Since you store the full URL, you can just do

`<a href="{{$book->download_link}}">{{$book->name}}</a>`

Comment: when i implement your solution, i got trying to get property of non-object error..
because when i click on the link suppose my site is `www.abn.com`
after clicking the link it redirects to `www.abn.com/https://bnbooks.com/1234`

Comment: Check what is stored in your database, is it `www.abn.com/https://bnbooks.com/1234` ?

Comment: The URL needs to have the protocol at the beginning or else it is a relative URL. With relative URLs, the browser links to the current host + the relative URL. So before storing in the database, it needs to start with `http://` or `https://`

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like

```
<a href="{{ $book->download_link }}">{{$book->name}}</a>
```

to show the url.

If you have a url like `/example/example` and you also want to show the domain name in front of the url, you do

```
<a href="{{ url($book->download_link) }}">{{$book->name}}</a>
```

This will create an url like `localhost:8000/example/example` (In case of localhost)

Answer (score 0):

Hope it works

```
<a href="{{ url('/'.$book->download_link) }}">{{$book->name}}</a>
```